# Using Keys & Values from Object as Values for Another

Tags: javascript, object

I have this data in var output (this is just an excerpt):

```
{
  'us-tx-021': 5,
  'us-tx-029': 3,
  'us-tx-031': 1,
}
```

I need to convert it to something like this:

```
[
  {
    'hc-key': "us-tx-021",
    'value': 5
  },
  {
    'hc-key': "us-tx-029",
    'value': 3
  },
  {
    'hc-key': "us-tx-031",
    'value': 1
  }
]
```

I don’t know how to use the keys & values from one object as values for another object. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Voting to close this as off topic (#3)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and where you're having problems before asking for people to do your job for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop to get all keys from original json

```
var json = '{ "us-tx-0212": 5, "us-tx-029": 3, "us-tx-031": 1}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var translatedObj = [];
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        translatedObj.push({'key': key, 'value': obj[key] });
    }
}
```

Comment: `{ 'us-tx-021': 5, 'us-tx-029': 3, 'us-tx-031': 1}` is not json, right?

Comment: @Vohuman: it's a valid json. Unfortunately I don't get what you're trying to say

Comment: It seems you don't know what JSON is. JSON is a string. `{ 'us-tx-021': 5, 'us-tx-029': 3, 'us-tx-031': 1}` is a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Vohuman: I see where you're trying to get. Fixed my example to avoid confusions

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. But OP didn't mention he/she is using JSON. Also that string is still not a valid JSON :) I just meant to say that using a different variable name is better than `json` for an object.